# Formating double field in mvc using jtable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
 $('#tXMLIndex').jtable({
            title: 'XML',
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            sorting: true,
            actions: {
                listAction: '/XmlParser/ListXML'
            },
            fields: {
                ...

                ,
                Price: {
                    title: 'Price'                 
                }
               ...
            }
            ,
```

This is my index view.
I want to format field price witch type is decimal with presison of 2 (100.00)

Comment: The code you have shown is incomplete.

Comment: Yes, but I just want to see how to format decimal field. Rest of the code works very well.